# Online auction system design resources

Tags: optimization

I’m interested in understanding how one might design online auctions (think Google, Facebook, eBay, etc.)

I’m curious how the price of a physical item, ad, NFT, etc might be a function of economic actors interests and behaviors.

This seems to be both a statistical inference problem and an optimization problem (hence interested in the OR perspective.)

Could you reference in relevant books or courses?